# General Primitive Element Theorem

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I have a proof of the primitive element theorem for subfields $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ which relies on there being infinitely many elements in $K$. In a book I've been reading it states that *every finite separable extension is simple* and that this follows from the earlier version the primitive element theorem.

Surely this doesn't work if I'm in a finite field? Is there another proof of the primitive element theorem that works in this case? Or is there a more general version that doesn't required infinitely many elements in $K$?

Comment: The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.

Comment: I'm not that sure Eagle ...
Edit : Oh didn't see "field" sorry.

Comment: Also be advised that in the context of finite fields *a primitive element* usually means a generator of the multiplicative group. This differs markedly from the context of arbitrary field extensions, where a primitive element is any element not contained in any intermediate field. The finite fields usage is more restrictive (even though a primitive element in that sense is also a primitive element in the more general sense).

Comment: But Chris' comment answers the question in the case of finite fields. Whenever I have seen this result stated, separate proofs have been stated for the two cases: infinite and finite.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: oh of course. So separate proofs in each case then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way of handling this is to deal with the infinite fields using the general theorem, and to deal with the finite fields using the cyclicity of the multiplicative group.
A finite degree extension of a finite field is itself finite, and the generator of its multiplicative group then is a primitive element in both senses of the word.